# How to initialize my ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have an Activity A which contains a list and an Activity B which displays the detail of an item from activity A using a fragment. There is a ViewPager in Activity B, which allows me to swipe left and right to view different item details in the list. The problem is where and how to initialize Activity B to display the details of the item I clicked in Activity A?

Below is my FragmentStatePagerAdapter class, currently no matter which item i clicked in activity A, it always launches the first item (though the swiping function is working)

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        Cursor data;
        ArticleDetailUpdateFragment detailUpdateFragment;

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Cursor data) {
            super(fm);
            this.data = data;

            detailUpdateFragment = new ArticleDetailUpdateFragment();
            long id = getIntent().getLongExtra(ArticleListActivity.EXTRA_ITEM_ID, -1);
            Log.d(TAG, "the itemId received in detail activity: " + String.valueOf(id));
            detailUpdateFragment.setId(id);

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.pager, detailUpdateFragment).commit();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            detailUpdateFragment = new ArticleDetailUpdateFragment();
            data.moveToPosition(position);
            long id = data.getLong(data.getColumnIndex(ItemsContract.Items._ID));
            detailUpdateFragment.setId(id);

            return detailUpdateFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return pageCount;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to get the position of the item clicked, assuming it is a recycler view, you can get the position by using this method

```
viewholder.getAdapterPosition()
```

Next you will have to pass this position in activityB using intent and set the viewpager's current item as this position after you have attached an adapter to your viewpager

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(position, false)
```

We pass in false because we dont want animation in the beginning